# $\frac 1 {1 + \epsilon} \le 1 - \frac \epsilon 2$ for $\epsilon \in (0, \frac 1 2)$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

How can we show that the following holds for $\epsilon \in (0, \frac 1 2)$?
$$
\frac 1 {1 + \epsilon} \le 1 - \frac \epsilon 2
$$

I thought, maybe it would be more convenient to try to show somehow that $\frac 1 {1 + \epsilon} + \frac \epsilon 2 \le 1$. And maybe use the fact that $\frac {1 + \epsilon} {1 - \epsilon} > 1 + 2 \epsilon$.

Best regards

Comment: As a rule of our community, I request you to please show your efforts in solving it. Thanks.

Comment: Edited at your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show this directly (and even for a wider interval for $\epsilon$) by rearranging the inequality:

$$\frac 1 {1 + \epsilon} \le 1 - \frac \epsilon 2 \Leftrightarrow 1\leq 1+\epsilon - \frac \epsilon 2(1+\epsilon) = 1 + \frac 12 \epsilon(1-\epsilon)$$

Since $\epsilon(1-\epsilon) \geq 0$ for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, you are done.